# List all PHP variables

Tags: php, variables, global-variables

Is it possible to dump all global variables in a PHP script? Say this is my code:

```
<?php
$foo = 1;
$bar = "2";
include("blah.php");
dumpall();
// displays $foo, $bar and all variables created by blah.php
```

Also, is it possible to dump all defined constants in a PHP script.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Use [`get_defined_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) and/or [`get_defined_constants`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php)

```
$arr = get_defined_vars();
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: and `get_defined_constants` for constants

Comment: $nico: Does this also work for variables created inside `eval()`?

Comment: @Salman As long as `get_defined_vars()`/`get_defined_constants()` is called after the `eval()`, then yes.

Comment: Just for those who are copy/pasting and want this in one line `echo "<pre>"; print_r(get_defined_vars()); die;` Copy whatever of that you want.

Answer (score 14):

When debugging trying to find differences using a program such as [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) (freeware) to see what differences various arrays and variables have you'll want to `ksort()` otherwise you'll get lots of false negatives. It also helps to visually format using the HTML `pre` element...

```
<?php
$everything = get_defined_vars();
ksort($everything);

?>
```

---

Edit: had to come back to this and realized I had a better answer, `$GLOBALS`.

```
$a = print_r(var_dump($GLOBALS),1);
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlspecialchars($a);
echo '</pre>';
```

---

Edit 2: as mpag mentioned `print_r()` may be susceptible to running out of memory if the software you're working with uses a lot. Presuming there is no output or it's clearly truncated *and* you have access to the `php.ini` file you can [adjust the memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16423653/606371) use as so:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
```

Comment: This answer is gold for me.

Comment: three comments: 1) `print_r` runs out of memory when using a class-heavy CMS, but `json_encode($GLOBALS)` with `console.log`ging javascript works. 2) Don't forget the $_ variables (SERVER, SESSION, ENV, FILES, COOKIE, GET, POST, REQUEST). 3) for more in-depth debugging i also do a `get_declared_classes` and iterate though those to `get_class_vars` and `get_class_methods`

Comment: @mpag Ah yes, I've seen some software use ludicrous amounts of memory; apparently the work around for that is to obviously either not use such a system but a lot of folks won't have that option so https://stackoverflow.com/a/16423653/606371 will hopefully work for them. Also if I recall correctly the `$_` variables should be pulled from `$GLOBALS`. Thanks for your comment, I'll look in to `get_declared_classes` and `get_class_vars` soon. :-)

Comment: I'm already setting my limit to 512M, and I believe it's unlikely that doubling to 1024 will resolve this issue in my case.  I believe 2048M is the hard limit for php.