# PHP print_r large array to variable not working

Tags: php, debugging, memory, printing

I'm trying to print_r a large array to a file to debug it. I've tried 2 methods:

```
$arr = get_large_array();
file_put_contents('file.txt', print_r($arr, true));
```

and

```
$arr = get_large_array();
ob_start();
print_r($arr);
file_put_contents('file.txt', ob_get_contents());
ob_end_clean();
```

In both cases, `file.txt` is not being created, and `$arr` is being echoed just like as if I had run `print_r($arr)`. What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that internally, `print_r($arr, true)` simply uses output buffering as in the second example. So behind the scenes, both methods are equivalent. But why is output buffering not working?

Intrigued, I replaced `$arr = get_large_array();` with `$arr = array();`. To my surprise, `file.txt` was created and there was no output. I had an idea. I changed `$arr` back to the large array, ran the code, and scrolled down to the end of the output. Sure enough, it was being truncated. I looked in the error log, and there were 20 or so "out of memory" errors occurring on the `print_r` line. In dealing with the large array, `print_r` ran out of memory, crashed and ignored the `file_put_contents` and the `ob_end_clean`, displaying the aforementioned symptoms.

For me, the solution was to increase the memory limit:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
```